# Script to start Weblogic servers and Managed servers

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Can someone help me to write script to perform below steps in weblogic.

1.Stop Managed Servers
2.Stop Node Manager
3.Stop Admin Server
4.Delete the tmp,cache folders.

Answer (score 1):

The steps you mentioned can be done with WLST and Node Manager. However, you need to make the following adjustments:

- Configure Node Manager/WebLogic Domain to stop using the demo SSL certificate when accessing/starting Node Manager.

  - Configure Node Manager

    > - Edit `nodemanager.properties` and set the following:
    >
    >   - `SecureListener` to `false`
    >   - `QuitEnabled` to `true`
    > - Restart Node Manager
  - Configure WebLogic Domain

    > - Login to WebLogic Domain
    > - Under *Environment*, *Machines*: click the Machine name configured
    > - Under *Configuration*, *Node Manager*: set **Type** to `Plain` and save
    > - Restart WebLogic Domain (Admin Server + Managed Servers)
  - Configure WebLogic Domain's Node Manager Credentials. The default is usually the username/password you entered when creating the WebLogic Domain. However, it is also a good idea to set different credentials for the Node Manager. This is totally optional, especially when working in a development environment.

    > - Login to WebLogic Domain
    > - Under *Domain Structure*, click the Weblogic Domain name
    > - Under *Security*, *General*: click **Advanced**
    > - Set the `NodeManager Username` and `NodeManager Password`/`Confirm NodeManager Password` and click **Save**
    >
    >   - For this answer, I will use `nodemanager`/`nodemanager_pwd` as sample values.

Assuming you have one Admin Server and one Managed Server, both on the same machine, write the following commands in a Python script:

```
# Connect to the Node Manager running on localhost with port 5556.
# Change the DOMAIN_NAME and the DOMAIN_HOME as appropriate
nmConnect('nodemanager','nodemanager_pwd','localhost','5556','DOMAIN_NAME','DOMAIN_HOME','PLAIN')

# Start the Admin Server. 
# The following command assumes that the 
# name of the Admin Server is AdminServer
nmServerStart('AdminServer')

# Start the Managed Server. Again, change the Managed Server name as appropriate
nmServerStart('Managed_Server_01')
```

To stop the Managed Server and Admin Server, it's the opposite direction with the sequence, and now you need to use the `nmKill` command. The `stopNodeManager()` is possible if the `QuitEnabled` property was set to `true` in the `nodemanager.properties` file.

```
nmConnect('nodemanager','nodemanager_pwd','localhost','5556','DOMAIN_NAME','DOMAIN_HOME','PLAIN')
nmKill('Managed_Server_01')
nmKill('AdminServer')
stopNodeManager()
```

When invoking the Python script that contains the commands above, execute the following command:

```
$MW_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh startup.py
$MW_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh shutdown.py
```

As for the clearing of the tmp/cache folders, these can all be done via shell script (assuming you're running on Linux)

Comment: Thanks for response...But if i want to use script for "SecureListener to false". Then how i can do?

Comment: The above is if `SecureListener` is set to `false`. If you mean to say that your `SecureListener` was set to `true`, then just use SSL instead of Plain. That applies on `nmConnect()` and on Machine configuration.

Then again, if you're just using the demo WebLogic SSL certificate instead of your own, it might be better to use Plain instead of SSL.